# Haskell Read - no parse error

Tags: haskell

I have a type called PartialDate

Then I have a function

```
readPartialDate :: String -> Maybe PartialDate
```

Bit of test code

```
main = do
        [d] <- getArgs
        return $ show $ readPartialDate d
```

```
runhaskell PartialDate.hs "12-2-2010"
"Just 12-2-2010"
```

All OK

Then I create a read simply by dispatching on readPartialDate:

```
instance Read PartialDate where
         readsPrec _ s = case (readPartialDate s) of
                              Nothing -> []
                              Just p -> [(p, s)]
```

Test code:

```
main = do
        [d] <- getArgs
        return $ show $ ((read d) :: PartialDate)
```

```
runHaskell PartialDate.hs 12-2-2010
PartialDate.hs: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Does anyone know why putting a working function into a read might give rise to a parse error?

readPartialDate uses Parsec, and also uses reverse, so might there be a laziness issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in the definition of `readsPrec`,

```
 readsPrec _ s = case (readPartialDate s) of
                      Nothing -> []
                      Just p -> [(p, s)]
```

you give the input String itself as the second component of the `readsPrec` result pair. `read` requires that the `reads` result have the second component empty, meaning that the entire input has been consumed to determine the value (in general, when you write `Read` instances, make sure you don't forget to consume trailing whitespace). Change the instance to

```
 readsPrec _ s = case (readPartialDate s) of
                      Nothing -> []
                      Just p -> [(p, "")]
```

and it should work.

Comment: @RobertOnslow: if this answered your question, remember to mark it as such.